# How to unmarshal WML / xhtml  into java ojbjects?

Tags: jaxb, wml

Is it possible to unmarshal WML or xhtml in java objects so that i can query the elements and save the values to DB?
I would like to unmarshal WML/Xhtml from [this](http://view-source%3ahttp://www.google.com/m/products/detail?cid=14154127892370052561&hl=en&loc=us#prd%3ao) link to java objects so that i can query the objects using JAXB.

Comment: WML/XHTML is just XML.  There are countless questions on StackOverflow on how to parse XML with Java.

Comment: Read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9275758) concerning the applicability of JAXB for XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use jaxp and XSLT to unmarshal the nodes into Java objects:

- [JAXP - XSLT sporadic test failures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271244/jaxp-xslt-sporadic-test-failures/5302077#5302077)
- [Unmarshalling with JaxB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html#unmars)